# Calculating "worth" of individual teams from combined scores

Tags: language-agnostic, probability, analysis

I have a whole bunch of data from a series of rounds. Specifically, I have many sets of sums of the points of three teams from a round(scores are not reported individually, only as a team).

For example, I would know teams 1, 7, 3 together earned 40 points in round 1, and that teams 1, 2,7 together earned 50 points in round 2.

I would like to use this data to determine which team is the best. My current method is to find the average score of the teams in the matches they competed in. However, this is rather inaccurate (results from test data had poor correlation to final placing in the final round)

I considered forming a series of equations, and using a matrix to solve this, but the teams do not score the same total each time( this is real world data).

So, is there a better formula to calculate the "worth" of these teams?

Comment: Interesting. You should better post this on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we want to find the "worth" of the teams, we'll need do better define it. Let w(n) denote the worth of team n.

If we'll assume that the score in each round is directly proportional to the team's worth, we can build the following set of equations:

- w(1)+w(7)+w(3)=40
- w(1)+w(2)+w(7)=50

According to the set of equations, we may have an exact solution.

However, a better model would be to assume that team g's worth is a [normally/geometric/other]-distributed variable, with mean w(g), and that the actual score in each game is a random sample (which is unknown). Let X(n,g) denote random sample n of group g. Hence,

- X(1,1)+X(1,7)+X(1,3)=40
- X(2,1)+X(1,2)+X(2,7)=50

I guess this model is more accurate, but requires much more sophisticated mathematics for estimating the worth of each team.